# node.js, odbc, monetdb - varchar attributes all null

Tags: node.js, null, odbc, varchar, monetdb

Friends of Code. I have a basic sample of odbc db lines running in node.js. Unfortunately for all db queries i make varchar attributes are reported as "null".

```
var db = require('odbc')()
  , cn = process.env.ODBC_CONNECTION_STRING
 ;

db.open(cn, function (err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);

  db.query('select * from users',  function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);

    console.log(data);

    db.close(function () {
      console.log('done');
    });
 });
});
```

Running this results as:

```
[ { name: null, fullname: null, default_schema: 2000 },
  { name: null, fullname: null, default_schema: 5899 } ]
done
```

While in monetdb it looks as follows:

```
+---------+---------------+----------------+
| name    | fullname      | default_schema |
+=========+===============+================+
| monetdb | MonetDB Admin |           2000 |
| wyh     | wyh analytics |           5899 |
+---------+---------------+----------------+
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

solved by node.js odbc team with odbc0.6.7

https://github.com/w1nk/node-odbc/issues/60

Thanks a lot!